# How to split or tokenize an array of strings by a space " " delimiter to find the second word in each string

Tags: c, string, sorting, parsing

I have an array that holds a bunch of strings. I want to find the second word in each of the strings that are contained in this array so I can sort the sentences alphabetically by the second word in the sentence. I tried using `strtok` but it doesn't work for tokenizing an array of strings. The delimiter is just the space between each word. I have to do this in C.

Comment: Please excuse, but "*it doesn't work*" is the more or less worth trouble report one can give.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: ... and `strtok()` would be the function of choice for tokenising.

Comment: an array of strings?  As in `char **` and the like rather than `char *`?  Provide a [MCVE] of your problem.

Comment: The problem with `strtok()` is of course that it *modifies* the input string.  Since the OP's objective is to sort the strings, this modification is probably undesirable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Valid point, indeed! So then I propose good old `strchr()` then.

Comment: Yes, `strchr()` should work, or `strcspn()`.  Additional alternatives are provided by various implementations.

Comment: "The delimiter is just the space between each word" --> With "abc<space><space>xyz", is "xyz" the 2nd or 3rd word?

Answer (score 1):

Sorting in C typically is done using [`qsort`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.5.2). The interface is generic, just the comparison function is specific to the sorting requirements.

Assuming the array's elements are C-strings, then the compare function in this case might look like this:

```
#include <string.h>

int cmp(const void * pv1, const void * pv2)
{
  const char * const * pp1 = pv1;
  const char * const * pp2 = pv2;

  const char * p1 = *pp1 ?*pp1 :""; /* Let's do it the ORxCLx way and tolerate NULLs, by treating them as empty-string. */
  const char * p2 = *pp2 ?*pp2 :""; /* Same. */

  /* Try to get space between 1st and 2nd word: */
  const char * pb1 = strchr(p1, ' ');
  const char * pb2 = strchr(p2, ' ');

  /* In case there was no 1st space
     make begin point to right after the 1st word's end: */
  pb1 = pb1 ?pb1+1 :p1 + strlen(p1);
  pb2 = pb2 ?pb2+1 :p2 + strlen(p2);

  /* Try to get space between 2nd and 3rd word: */
  const char * pe1 = strchr(pb1, ' ');
  const char * pe2 = strchr(pb2, ' ');

  /* In case there was no 2nd space
     make end point right after the 2nd's word's end: */
  pe1 = pe1 ?pe1 :pb1 + strlen(pb1);
  pe2 = pe2 ?pe2 :pb2 + strlen(pb2);

  /* Calculate 2nd word's length: */
  size_t s1 = (size_t)(pe1 - pb1);
  size_t s2 = (size_t)(pe2 - pb2);

  return strncmp(pb1, pb2, s1 > s2 ?s2 :s1);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *, const void *);

int main(void)
{
  const char * as[] = {
    "e 5 y",
    "b 2",
    "c 3 z",
    "d 4 x",
    "c 3 ",
    "a 1",
    "c 3"
  };

  qsort(as, sizeof as / sizeof *as, sizeof *as, cmp);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof as / sizeof *as; ++i)
  {
    printf("'%s'\n", as[i]);
  }
}
```

and get:

```
'a 1'
'b 2'
'c 3 z'
'c 3'
'c 3 '
'd 4 x'
'e 5 y'
```

Comment: I think `pb1 = p1 + strcspn(p1, " "); s1 = strcspn(pb1, " ");` would be a good alternative simplification.